# How can I convert this iterative statement into a recursive statement?

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, iteration

So I have this programming project in which I need to create a program that determines if a number is a perfect square, and if so, write it into a .txt document. This is very easy and effective to do with a for loop, however, the instructions for the assignment say that the program should accomplish this using recursion. This is the iterative statement I came up with:

```
double division;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++) {
            division = (Math.sqrt(inputs.get(i)));
            if (division == (int)division) {
                pw.println(inputs.get(i));
                 }
            }
```

Where `inputs` is an ArrayList that is created by reading the inputs of the user.
This solves the problem, but like I said, it needs to be a recursive statement. I know that for recursion I need a base case that will eventually make the method stop calling itself, but I can't figure out what the base case would be. Also, I've seen several examples of converting from iteration to recursion, but all of these examples use a single `int` variable, and in my case I need to do it with an ArrayList.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: your function has nothing to do with the fact that inputs() is an arraylist ... it only uses inputs.get(i) which is just a single integer variable.

Comment: True, I hadn't thought of it that way

Answer (score 1):

For recursive function, you can use bynary search algorithm:

```
 int checkPerfectSquare(long N,  
                              long start, 
                              long last) 
{ 
    // Find the mid value 
    // from start and last 
    long mid = (start + last) / 2; 
  
    if (start > last) 
    { 
        return -1; 
    } 
  
    // Check if we got the number which 
    // is square root of the perfect 
    // square number N 
    if (mid * mid == N) 
    { 
        return (int)mid; 
    } 
  
    // If the square(mid) is greater than N 
    // it means only lower values then mid 
    // will be possibly the square root of N 
    else if (mid * mid > N) 
    { 
        return checkPerfectSquare(N, start,  
                                  mid - 1); 
    } 
  
    // If the square(mid) is less than N 
    // it means only higher values then mid 
    // will be possibly the square root of N 
    else 
    { 
        return checkPerfectSquare(N, mid + 1,  
                                  last); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fact that a square number is the sum of the odd integers. E.g.

1+3 = 4 = 2^2

1+3+5 = 9 = 3^2

1+3+5+7 = 16 = 4^2, etc

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
      if (isSquare(i)) System.out.println(i);     
    }
  }
  public static boolean isSquare(int n) {
    if (n==0 || n==1) return true;
    return isSquare(n,1,1);
  }

  private static boolean isSquare(int n, int sum, int odd) {
    if (n==sum) return true;
    if (n < sum) return false;
    odd += 2;
    sum += odd;
    return isSquare(n, sum, odd);
  }
```

output:

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
100
121
144
169
196
225
256
289
324
361
400
441
484
529
576
625
676
729
784
841
900
961
```

Answer (score 0):

You could recursively check if the square of any smaller int is equal to your input.

```
public static boolean isSquare(int n) {
  if (n==0 || n==1) return true;
  return isSquare(n, 1);
}

private static boolean isSquare(int n, int i) {
  if (i*i == n) return true;
  if (i*i > n) return false;
  return isSquare(n,i+1);
}
```